# What is a "polynomially bounded" function, and why is this a requirement of the The Delta Method?

Tags: probability, estimation, approximation, convergence, delta-method

I am reading a paper ["A note on the Delta Method" by Gary Oehlert, JASA, 1992](http://pds8.egloos.com/pds/200805/26/44/2684406.pdf).

I am trying to estimate the variance of a function of a random variable, but first I want to understand the limitations of using the Delta Method Taylor series.

Oehlert states:$^1$

> when the function we are approximating is polynomially bounded in the random variables, then the naive Taylor series approximation will yield the correct asymptotic approximation..."

How can I tell if a function is polynomially bounded? Why is this a requirement of using the naive Taylor series approximation?

Is the alternative to a naive Taylor seires a higher-order Taylor series or a different approximation?

$^1$ *p 28, middle of right col, last paragraph before Examples*

Comment: For the definition of polynomially bounded, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109352/meaning-of-polynomially-bounded) math.se question.

Comment: At first glance it appears to me that polynomial boundeness is not a necessary condition (requirement) but a sufficient condition for the approximation in the Theorem to have accuracy $O(n^{−\beta})$. This is actually clarified by the author in Example 3. An approximation of order $O(n^{−(q+1)/2})$ is presented in $(3)$ where the assumptions are: $g$ and its first $q+1$ derivatives are bounded in a neighbourhood of $w$. I do not believe there is a practical general method to check polynomial boundeness. You can check, for example, how their ratio/difference behaves in the region of interest.

Comment: @MånsT thanks for the [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109352/meaning-of-polynomially-bounded). I posted a 100 point bounty, ending in seven days, requesting more details.

Comment: @David, it doesn't look like you've posted a bounty.

Comment: @Macro The bounty is posted on the linked question at math.SE http://math.stackexchange.com/q/109352/3733